# Allow the user to change CSS design elements with a dropdown menu?

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, themes

So, since I have problems deciding an absolute theme for my site, I'd like to let the user choose a theme from a dropdown menu, and when an option is clicked, it'll change the background image, background color, and background positioning.

eg. If the user chose the "Mario Bros 3" theme, they'd get

```
background-image:url('smb3.jpg');
background-repeat:repeat-x;
background-position:left bottom;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-color: #6899f8;
```

And if you select "Zelda LTTP" theme, you'd get

```
background-image:url('zeldalttp.jpg');
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:left bottom;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-color: Black;
```

I'd like this to be in a dropdown menu, and have it remember your choice, so that it applies every time.

I have next to no idea how to do this, can anybody help?

Comment: You know about JavaScript, right? It does these kinds of things... `:P`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'd select the themes by different classes on the body, like that:

```
body.smb2{
    background-image:url('smb3.jpg');
    background-repeat:repeat-x;
    background-position:left bottom;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: #6899f8;
}
body.zelda{
    background-image:url('zeldalttp.jpg');
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
    background-position:left bottom;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-color: Black;
}
```

Then set the body class with javascript (or server-side) and save the choice in a cookie.

---

Exactly, put the css in a css file then you could change it like that:

HTML:

```
<select id="select">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="smb2">SMB 2</option>
    <option value="zelda">Zelda</option>
</select>
```

pure JS:

```
var sel = document.getElementById('select');
sel.onchange = function(){
    document.body.className = sel.value;
};
```

or [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) if you prefer:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    $('body').prop('class',$(this).val());    
});
```

---

Ok the problem on your site is, that the body already has a bunch of other classes. And className overwrites all of them.
One solution would be to save the old classes and then add the new ones like that:

```
var saveclass = null;
var sel = document.getElementById('select');
sel.onchange = function(){
    saveclass = saveclass ? saveclass : document.body.className;
    document.body.className = saveclass + ' ' + sel.value;
};
```

or jQuery:

```
var currentclass = null;
$('select').change(function(){
    $('body').removeClass(currentclass).addClass($(this).val());
    currentclass = $(this).val();
});
```

Comment: I really appreciate the reply, I just wish I knew a little more about where I'm putting this code exactly?
I guess I'd put it in the CSS file, and somehow call it with the dropdown menu?

Comment: Thanks, that's a great help! I got the actual dropdown working, but it doesn't appear to be able to pull the CSS together, like it can't find the body.zelda or body.smb3.
The site is http://dcvidya.com/
As you can see, it just totally breaks the sites CSS.
I've included the pure JS and the HTML in a widget, and put the CSS you gave me into the themes core CSS file.
Any ideas?

Comment: Okay, this seems to be getting somewhere.
The problem now is, instead of breaking it, it simply doesn't do anything.
I think it's possibly remembering the background information as well as everything else? Not too sure...

Comment: @DANKCUBE you apply the style on `.page.zelda` but you don't have an element with class page, only one with id page and you set the zelda class on the body, not the #page element. so instead of `.page.zelda` you could write `.zelda #page` and `.smb2 #page`

Comment: Fantastic! Works totally fine now, is there an easy way to make it save to a cookie?

Answer (score 0):

If you look into WordPress' or numerous message boards' theming architecture, they'd normally serve separate css files depending on user selection. That would, however, be justifiable if you have significant difference styling both themes (i.e. more than one line background difference) making sure redundant css is not received by the client.

If the differences are minor, Andy's answer would work well. And yes, *do save the choice in a cookie* - this would allow for their preference to be saved even without a profile stored on the server, meaning they don't have to re-select the correct theme every time they visit the site.