# How to change background color gradient with a Drop down

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to have some user input in changing the background color but I wanted to create a few gradients that they can select from a drop down and then it will change the background color. I used this code (below) and it oddly enough works in JSFiddle with my code but when I run it on the browser its not working.

[Allow the user to change CSS design elements with a dropdown menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10874265/allow-the-user-to-change-css-design-elements-with-a-dropdown-menu)

I deleted all my code down to just the elements in the code above and it still didn't work. I am not sure what is going wrong in this situation.

```js
var sel = document.getElementById('selectColor');
sel.onchange = function() {
  document.body.className = sel.value;
};
```

```css
body.PurpleGradient {
  background-color: #6899f8
}

body.BlueGradient {
  background: linear-gradient(to right bottom, #6614e5, #620fc3, #5a0ca4, #510c85, #450d69);
}
```

```html
<select id="selectColor">
  <option value=""></option>
  <option value="PurpleGradient">Purple2</option>
  <option value="BlueGradient">Blue</option>
</select>
```

This all works in JSfiddle but when I apply it to my site nothing happens. I thought it might have something to do with the body but I added the code shown at that link and it still does nothing. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I know the gradient repeats, this is just an example of what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: By default, JSFiddle wraps all JS in a page-load event. This is important because you're trying to find an element on the page(`selectColor`), however if your code is not in a page-load event, it will run instantly - before the `selectColor` element has loaded on the page. Are you including a page-load event when you move the code to your side? Or including the `<script>` at the bottom your `<body>`? Additionally, when you run your page, are there any errors in the console?

Comment: You sir are amazing. I just put the script at the bottom of my body and it works now, I can't thank you enough I can't believe I overlooked this all day.